# MySQL query to count items by week for the current 52-weeks?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, calendar

I have a query that I'd like to change so that it gives me the counts for the **current** 52 weeks. This query makes use of a calendar table I've made which contains a list of dates in a fixed range. The query as it stands is selecting max and min dates and not necessarily the last 52 weeks.

I'm wondering how to keep my calendar table current such that I can get the last 52-weeks (i.e, from right now to one year ago). Or is there another way to make the query independent of using a calendar table?

Here's the query:

```
SELECT calendar.datefield AS date, IFNULL(SUM(purchaseyesno),0) AS item_sales
FROM items_purchased join items on items_purchased.item_id=items.item_id 
RIGHT JOIN calendar ON (DATE(items_purchased.purchase_date) = calendar.datefield)
WHERE (calendar.datefield BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(DATE(purchase_date)) 
FROM items_purchased) AND (SELECT MAX(DATE(purchase_date)) FROM items_purchased)) 
GROUP BY week(date)
```

thoughts?

Comment: Why do you have a calendar table and aren't just using a DATE or DATETIME column in that table?

Comment: @Ryan Kempt, that may indeed be what the OP is asking. In addition, date functions aren't as helpful when you need a sequence of dates.

Comment: Calendar tables are used when you have to have a bin for each period and there may not be data for any particular bin.

Comment: hi Ryan, the calendar table is to generate item sales of 0 for a given date when their were no purchases, otherwise the query results are restricted to only the dates where there was an item sale. My end use is to graph the results so having **all** dates and not just dates with non-zero values is important, thanks Jim and Jason for helping Clarify!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some people dislike this approach but I tend to use a dummy table that contains values from 0 - 1000 and then use a derived table to produce the ranges that are needed -

```
CREATE TABLE dummy (`num` INT NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO dummy VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), .... (999), (1000);
```

If you have a table with an auto-incrementing id and plenty of rows you could generate it from that -

```
CREATE TABLE `dummy`
SELECT id AS `num` FROM `some_table` WHERE `id` <= 1000;
```

Just remember to insert the 0 value.

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL num DAY
FROM dummy
WHERE num < 365
```

So, applying this approach to your query you could do something like this -

```
SELECT WEEK(calendar.datefield) AS `week`, IFNULL(SUM(purchaseyesno),0) AS item_sales
FROM items_purchased join items on items_purchased.item_id=items.item_id 
RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL num DAY) AS datefield
    FROM dummy
    WHERE num < 365
) AS calendar ON (DATE(items_purchased.purchase_date) = calendar.datefield)
WHERE calendar.datefield >= (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
GROUP BY week(datefield) -- shouldn't this be datefield instead of date?
```

Comment: hi nnichols, thanks so much, i'll give this a shot, why don't people like this approach? Cause the code looks ugly? or query is slow? or...?

Comment: I am not sure why. There should not be any performance issue with this at all and personally, I think it is a rather elegant solution.

Comment: Ok I made the dummy table. Thanks for the advice there. However, i think i'm confused specifically on your statement: `WHERE calendar.datefield >= (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 YEAR)`.  As it stands, my calendar table goes from jan 2008 to sept 2010. Does the equality mean I have to keep updating my calendar table to stay within the last year? By the way, your query yields 52 weeks of item sales if I `group by week(datefield)` and not `group by week(date)`. `date` is not defined. However, i'm still not sure if these 52 weeks of item sales are the most recent 52 weeks or not. Thoughts?

Comment: Sorry was cut off by the 5 minute editing time limit...i'm not sure if these 52 weeks of item sales are the most recent 52 weeks or not as I can't see the actual date. The `week` field is just numerical 1 through 52. Thoughts?

Comment: That WHERE clause was just an example of how to filter for everything greater than one year ago. If you run the query `SELECT CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL num DAY FROM dummy WHERE num < 365` you should see a list of dates representing all days for the last year. This is then joined to your items_purchased table. So, it should be giving you sales for the past year, by week. Add MAX(calendar.datefield) to your field list so you can see the last day in each week, or MIN() if you prefer.

Comment: wow, this `SELECT CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL num DAY FROM dummy WHERE num < 365` statement seems like magic! so I guess I will never need to update my calender table? I guess the logic here is somewhat analogous to generating 1000 table rows using `CREATE TABLE `dummy`
SELECT id AS `num` FROM `some_table` WHERE `id` <= 1000;`

Answer (score 1):

I too typically "simulate" a table on the fly by using @sql variables and just join to ANY table in your system that has AT least as many weeks as you want.  NOTE... when dealing with dates, I like to typically use the date-part only which implies a 12:00:00 am.  Also, by advancing the start date by 7 days for the "EndOfWeek", you can now apply a BETWEEN clause for records within a given time period... such as your weekly needs.

I've applied such a sample to coordinate the join based on date association to the per week basis...  Since your

```
select 
      DynamicCalendar.StartOfWeek,
      COALESCE( SUM( IP.PurchaseYesNo ), 0 ) as Item_Sales
   from 
      ( select
              @weekNum := @weekNum +1 as WeekNum,
              @startDate as StartOfWeek,
              @startDate := date_add( @startDate, interval 1 week ) EndOfWeek
           from 
              ( select @weekNum := 0,
                       @startDate := date(date_sub(now(), interval 1 year ))) sqlv,
              AnyTableThatHasAtLeast52Records,
           limit
             52 ) DynamicCalendar
      LEFT JOIN items_purchased IP
         on IP.Purchase_Date bewteen DynamicCalendar.StartOfWeek 
                            AND DynamicCalendar.EndOfWeek
   group by
      DynamicCalendar.StartOfWeek
```

This is under the premise that your "PurchaseYesNo" value is in your purchased table directly.  If so, no need to join to the ITEMS table.  If the field IS in the items table, then I would just tack on a LEFT JOIN for your items table and get value from that.

However you could use the dynamicCalendar context in MANY conditions.